# Error in Odoo8 installation- "column ir_ui_view.active does not exist"

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, installation, odoo

I was running Openerp 7 earlier, then updated the code to Odoo8 RC1 on my Ubuntu 13.04, with Postgre Sql 1.16.1 database and Eclipse 3.8 IDE. Now I wanted to update to Odoo8.0 , when I downloaded the code from GitHub and tried to run the server from eclipse, I got this error:
"column ir_ui_view.active does not exist"

I understand here that Odoo8 has added another column to the ir_ui_view table, but how should I fix it on my side to get my server running. I dont want to go through the entire process to setup Postgresql, creating user, assigning roles and then installing odoo. Can I have a simple solution where I can edit the server file or change any database property to get this running. I went through few links but none could help much.

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a clean database in Odoo's database manager (`/web/database/manager`) without having to "go through the entire process to setup Postgresql, creating user, assigning roles"...

Comment: Thanks Ludwik. I understand what you just mentioned.. But for that my server need to start. My server is not starting. Whenever I start the server I land into this issue. Only if I could make the server start properly, I can create a clean database from the Odoo's database manager. Let me know your suggestions.

Comment: `/web/database/manager` is often accessible even if the server throws errors and the rest of the system doesn't work. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes I had tried. But I missed mentioning that. However I now land into other issues like "No module named passlib.context" followed by "QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: web.login".. So again on fixing the error "No module named passlib.context" by sudo apt-get install passlib , I get error "Unable to locate package passlib". So I am still unable to get the server running on a new database

Comment: There is a `requiremenst.txt` file included with Odoo 8, so just do `pip install -r requiremenst.txt`.

Comment: Thanks Ludwik for all the help. I was missing the passlib module. sudo apt-get install python-passlib did the work for me. As you said I have tried creating a clean database first via /web/database/manager and then started resolving issues. There was a long stack trace of errors, but installation of passlib was all that was required.

Answer (score 0):

OpenERP/Odoo databases are incompatible between major versions.
They must first be upgraded.

This can be done by OpenERP support services or by yourself using tools such as [OpenUpgrade](https://github.com/OpenUpgrade).

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get install python-pass`